# Question about Prolog matching

Tags: prolog, matching

I'm brand new to prolog and I'm trying to match something along the lines of this:

rule(blah Variable, ...).

Basically I'm trying to match the atom "blah" followed by any expression. Is this possible?

Comment: Doesn't seem possible. Explain what you want to do and maybe we can assist with the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SWI you can use atom_concat/3:

```
rule(X, ....):-
  atom_concat(blah, Y, X),
   ...
```

e.g.:  Suppose X=blahsomethingelse then
atom_concat(blah, Y, X) will instantiate Y with somethingelse.
Note that atom_concat works only with atoms.